# Cisco APIC: How to get model name for each controller, spine, and leaf via CLI

Tags: cisco

What is the command to get model name for each controller, spine, and leaf via CLI?

`show version` don't have it.

```
APIC03# show version
 Role        Pod         Node        Name             Version              
 ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------  ---------------- 
 controller  1           1           APIC01         3.2(4e)              
 controller  2           2           APIC02         3.2(4e)                       
 spine       1           1           SPINE01        n9000-13.2(4e)       
 spine       1           2           SPINE02        n9000-13.2(4e)       
 leaf        1           1           LEAF01         n9000-13.2(4e)       
 leaf        1           2           LEAF02         n9000-13.2(4e)
```

`show switch` shows more info, but still no model name in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same approach is used [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58655/how-to-access-particular-node-from-cisco-apic-via-ssh/63797#63797). Login to APIC CLI and get node IDs:

```
APIC# moquery -c fabricNode -f 'fabric.Node.role=="leaf"' | egrep ^id | order
id               : 101
id               : 102
id               : 103
id               : 104
id               : 105
id               : 106

APIC# moquery -c fabricNode -f 'fabric.Node.role=="spine"' | egrep ^id | order
id               : 201
id               : 202
```

Then display devices version:

```
APIC# fabric 101-106 show version
----------------------------------------------------------------
 Node 101 (XXXX-DC-LEAF-101)
----------------------------------------------------------------
Cisco Nexus Operating System (NX-OS) Software
TAC support: http://www.cisco.com/tac
Documents: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9372/tsd_products_support_series_home.html
Copyright (c) 2002-2014, Cisco Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.
The copyrights to certain works contained in this software are
owned by other third parties and used and distributed under
license. Certain components of this software are licensed under
the GNU General Public License (GPL) version 2.0 or the GNU
Lesser General Public License (LGPL) Version 2.1. A copy of each
such license is available at
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php and
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.php

Software
  BIOS:      version 05.31
  kickstart: version 14.0(3d) [build 14.0(3d)]
  system:    version 14.0(3d) [build 14.0(3d)]
  PE:        version 4.0(3d)
...

APIC# fabric 201-202 show version
----------------------------------------------------------------
 Node 201 (XXXX-DC-SPINE-201)
----------------------------------------------------------------
Cisco Nexus Operating System (NX-OS) Software
TAC support: http://www.cisco.com/tac
Documents: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps9372/tsd_products_support_series_home.html
Copyright (c) 2002-2014, Cisco Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.
The copyrights to certain works contained in this software are
owned by other third parties and used and distributed under
license. Certain components of this software are licensed under
the GNU General Public License (GPL) version 2.0 or the GNU
Lesser General Public License (LGPL) Version 2.1. A copy of each
such license is available at
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php and
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.php

Software
  BIOS:      version 05.31
  kickstart: version 14.0(3d) [build 14.0(3d)]
  system:    version 14.0(3d) [build 14.0(3d)]
  PE:        version 4.0(3d)
...
```

`APIC# show controller detail id <ID>` will display controller info.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. I'm new to ACI, APIC ... Learn a lot from you. Appreciate it.

Comment: Usually SNMP is used for that task. Have you looked at the LLDP or CDP local information output? Most often, that contains most of the information.

Comment: @Zac67 CDP is not used between fabric nodes and LLDP unfortunately doesn't give too much info.